# MySQL: Set value in column based on other tables data (need optimize)

Tags: mysql, sql-update, multiple-records

I have two tables in a MySQL v8 database.

Table `relations`

| child_id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 1 |
| 13 | 1 |
| 21 | 2 |
| 23 | 2 |

Table `dates`

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 11 | 2023-05-15 |
| 12 | NULL |
| 13 | 0000-00-00 |
| 2 | 2023-07-01 |
| 21 | 2023-07-01 |
| 23 | 2023-07-01 |

I need to update disintegrated (0000-00-00 or NULL) dates in first table, basing on data from second and first table.

1. get `id` for row with 0000-00-00 or NULL in `dates`
2. get `parent_id` in `relations` for `child_id` which equals found `id` from `dates`
3. get `date` for `id` from `dates` which equals found `parent_id`
4. update `date` in `dates` by this found one for `id` (from first step)

Example:

1. found NULL date and for it dates.id is 12
2. for relations.child_id = 12 get value of relations.parent_id = 1
3. for dates.id = 1 get value of dates.date = 2023-01-01
4. for dates.id = 12 set value dates.date = 2023-01-01

I wrote something like this - attempt with subqueries:

```
UPDATE dates d1
SET d1.date = (SELECT d2.date 
               FROM 
                   (SELECT * FROM dates) d2 
               WHERE d2.id = (SELECT r.parent_id 
                              FROM relations r 
                              WHERE r.child_id = d2.id))
WHERE CAST(d1.date AS UNSIGNED) = 0;
```

Attempt with joins:

```
UPDATE dates d1
LEFT JOIN relations r ON (d1.id = r.child_id)
SET d1.date = (SELECT d2.date 
               FROM (SELECT * FROM dates) d2 
               WHERE d2.child_id = r.parent_id)
WHERE CAST(dates.date AS UNSIGNED) > 0
```

**What I need**

Both solutions work, but they are very heavy.

Is there any other, lighter and smoother, solution?

Answer (score 1):

if there is only one step to the date you can use

```
UPDATE dates d1
SET d1.`date` = 
(SELECT d2.`date` FROM (SELECT * FROM dates) d2 JOIN relations r ON r.`parent_id`  = d2.id 
  AND r.Child_id = d1.id) 
  WHERE d1.`date` IS NULL OR d1.`date` = '0000-00-00'
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM dates
```

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 11 | 2023-05-15 |
| 12 | 2023-01-01 |
| 13 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2 | 2023-07-01 |
| 21 | 2023-07-01 |
| 23 | 2023-07-01 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/H2JOPgvm)